# Alternatives to Waves S360° Imager plugin?

Tags: panning, plugin, rotate, euphonix, waves

Hi all

Do you know any alternative plugin to the Waves S360 (I work with Pro Tools)? I'm looking for something like the Rotate function in the Euphonix console: the Waves S360 imager is the only thing I know that is similar.

Any other plugin or trick to do that in Pro Tools?

Best

Davide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spanner is a new AAX plugin from maggot which does the kind of thing you are asking.
www.maagot.co.nz/software/spanner.shtml

Comment: Thanks Justin, great, lots of possibilities, and awesome GUI. hope to see the Rotate function implemented soon. Best

Answer (score 4):

[This one](http://www.fluxhome.com/products/freewares/stereotool) from Flux is free although it doesn't exactly do the rotate like Waves.

I haven't used this one but [Wave Arts Panarama](http://wavearts.com/products/plugins/panorama/) looks intriguing.

It is also, of course, easy to change the stereo imaging of a sound by adjusting the L and the R levels individually or applying delay or reverb asymmetrically. If you are mixing in 5.1 it is easy to rotate using the ProTools 5.1 panner.

Comment: Thanks. I know those plugins, but they work (as the Pro Tools panner) only for mono or stereo tracks. What I'm looking for is something that let me rotate a LCR, QUAD or 5.0 track into a 5.1 mix. Don't know if I'm explaining myself well, sorry ;)

Comment: Ah...I see. IRCAM Spat may work for this: http://www.fluxhome.com/products/plug_ins/ircam_spat

Answer (score 1):

@ Justin: looks good...awesome!